# if statements not working for some test cases

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

This code is not working for the test case `17 13 3 15`. In other test cases that I tried, it worked perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int max;
    a=max;
    if(b>max)
    max=b;
    if(c>max)
    max=c;
    if(d>max)
    max=d;
    return max;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use braces fot if statements. This habit will prevent future mistakes.  Also check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: ed hel i already used braces in if statements.

Comment: i think you are talking about curly braces..as i am not using multiple statements it's not necessary to use braces

Comment: Use braces. Saves on embarrassing situations. Humor aside - makes code easier to read.  Macro expansion is a problem. Also somebody adds to the if clause but forgets there no braces...

Comment: i will definitely consider it in my next code.

Comment: Read up on six signa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this statement

```
a=max;
```

to

```
max = a;
```